How can I add a colspan (or any attribute) to a <td>?
I have a form with a couple of fields and the results are displayed as a table using
$form[$form_key] = [
      '#type' => 'table',
      '#caption' => $title,
...

I can add attributes to the tr with
$form[$form_key][$key]['#attributes']['class'] = 'comment';

and contents to the tds with
$form[$form_key][$key][$col] = ['#markup' => 'ccccccccccc'];

but
$form[$form_key][$key][$col]['#attributes']['class'] = 'td-comment';

does not get rendered.
I tried to manually render with
 $html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($form);

and then fix the html manually, which worked but the form fields did not render properly

Can you show the entire declaration of the form table please? You've only showed bits of it.

Use '#wrapper_attributes' for the table cell attributes. This allows you to set classes or other attributes on the  tag. #wrapper_attributes is used to set the attributes on the  element, such as classes, id, or other attributes. whereas #attributes is used for setting attributes on rows (), not individual cells.
Here’s an example:
$form[$form_key] = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#caption' => $title,
  '#header' => [
    t('Column 1'),
    t('Column 2'),
  ],
];

// Row 1
$form[$form_key]['row_1'] = [
  '#attributes' => ['class' => ['row-class']],
];

$form[$form_key]['row_1']['column_1'] = [
  '#markup' => 'Cell 1, Row 1',
  '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => ['td-class-1']],
];

$form[$form_key]['row_1']['column_2'] = [
  '#markup' => 'Cell 2, Row 1',
  '#wrapper_attributes' => ['class' => ['td-class-2']],
];


This does work,eg also with:   $form[$form_key]['row_1']['column_3'] = [   '#markup' => 'Cell 3, Row 1',   '#wrapper_attributes' => ['style' => 'color:red'], ]; $form[$form_key]['row_1']['column_4'] = [   '#markup' => 'Cell 4, Row 1',   '#wrapper_attributes' => ['colspan' => '9'], ];
